# How to select data from the following table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

With table data as:

[image]

How to obtain the result as:

[image]

Comment: Include some code that shows what you have tried so far.

Comment: @Pooja-G You can't determine whether my output is correct or not. i asked here for that output. i got the output myself and i posted below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select category_name,parent_category_name from tbl_product p

left join 
(
    select cp.category_code, 
        case
            when
                cp.parent_code = 0 then ''
            when
                cp.parent_code != 0 then cp.category_name
        end as category_name,
        cp.parent_code, isnull(ch.category_name, cp.category_name) as parent_category_name from tbl_category cp
        left join 
        (
            select cl.category_name, cl.category_code, cl.parent_code from tbl_category cl
        ) ch on cp.parent_code = ch.category_code
) as cat
 on cat.category_code = p.category_code
```

Answer (score 1):

Your expected output is causing confusion. I thought you expect the below format as output.

```
DECLARE @CategoriesDetails TABLE (category_code INT, parent_code INT, category_name VARCHAR(100));

INSERT INTO @CategoriesDetails (category_code, parent_code, category_name) VALUES
(1, 0, 'Food'),
(2, 1, 'Bakery'),
(3, 2, 'Snaks');

SELECT  C1.category_name AS [Sub category], 
        ISNULL(C2.category_name, '') AS [Parent category]
FROM @CategoriesDetails C1
LEFT JOIN @CategoriesDetails C2 ON C2.category_code = C1.parent_code
```

Output:

```
Sub category    Parent category
--------------------------------
Food            
Bakery          Food
Snaks           Bakery
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to `LEFT JOIN` with itself as the below.

```
SELECT  
    T.categroy_name,
    COALESCE(Parent.category_name, '') AS 'parent category'
FROM
    Tbl T LEFT JOIN 
    Tbl Parent ON T.parent_code = Parent.categrory_code
```